# Plot xrange graph in x axis not in the middle

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts to chart a graph to monitor during the 24 hours when a printer is printing and when a printer is doing nothing. 
I've accomplished it using the xrange type, and everything is ok. 
The only issue i'm having is that graph is plotted in the middle of the graph and i'd like it to be drawed in the bottom. What should i check?
This is the code i use to create the graph

```
Highcharts.chart('chart', {
        chart: {
            type: 'xrange'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointPlacement: 'on',
                colors: ["#00e205"],
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            plotBands: bands,
            startOnTick: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            startOnTick: false,
            categories: ['Stampa'],
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        legend : {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return "Inizio stampa: "+moment(this.x).format('H:mm:ss')+" <br />Fine stampa:"+moment(this.x2).format('H:mm:ss')
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Plotter'
        }
    });
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable **startOnTick** property and set proper **min** value for yAxis:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0.45,
    startOnTick: false
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o3kxbcum/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min